# Android webrtc still running after app exited with back button

Tags: android, kotlin, webrtc

I'm new to Webrtc, I'm using the AWS Webrtc demo with Android Nav Component. When I exited the app with the back button, I can see that Webrtc is still running or I can see the following log:

```
EglRenderer: cameraSurfaceViewDropping frame - No surface
```

In my fragment at the onStop method my code is as follow:

```
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(null)

        if (rootEglBase != null) {
            rootEglBase!!.release()
            rootEglBase = null
        }

        if (remoteView != null) {
            remoteView!!.release()
            remoteView = null
        }

        if (localPeer != null) {
            localPeer!!.dispose()
            localPeer = null
        }

        if (videoSource != null) {
            videoSource!!.dispose()
            videoSource = null
        }

        if (videoCapturer != null) {
            try {
                videoCapturer?.stopCapture()
                videoCapturer?.dispose()
            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                Timber.e("Failed to stop webrtc video capture. $e ")
            }
            videoCapturer = null
        }

        if (client != null) {
            this.client!!.disconnect()
            this.client = null
        }
        peerConnectionFoundMap.clear()
        pendingIceCandidatesMap.clear()
```

However, I can see the problem only when I exited the app through the back button, if I killed the app, I don't get the log. Has anyone experienced this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way you should destroy your WebRTC session on `onDestroy()` or `onStop()`.

```
    if (videoCaptureAndroid != null) {
        videoCaptureAndroid?.stopCapture()
        videoCaptureAndroid = null
    }
    if (localPeer != null) {
        localPeer?.close()
        localPeer = null
    }
    if (videoSource != null) {
        videoSource?.dispose()
        videoSource = null
    }
    if (audioSource != null) {
        audioSource?.dispose()
        audioSource = null
    }
    if (localAudioTrack != null) {
        localAudioTrack?.dispose()
        localAudioTrack = null
    }
    if (currentRemoteMediaStream != null) {
        currentRemoteMediaStream?.dispose()
        currentRemoteMediaStream = null
    }
    if (localVideoView != null) {
        localVideoView?.release()
        localVideoView = null
    }
    if (remoteVideoView != null) {
        remoteVideoView?.release()
        remoteVideoView = null
    }
    rootEglBase.release();
```

Comment: There is something wrong with this way of disposing. Some components dispose other components. For example the stream will dispose the tracks, and then you will get an exception when you try to dispose them again. The same problem happens even if the change the order.

Comment: I tried and verified this a long time ago. Will update the answer if I found any issue once I get time.

Comment: The overall idea is working great, I'm telling future users before implementing it you need to check the code of each dispose method whether it disposes other components or not, if it does then make a suitable order not to get a crash or create an extension like tryDispose which uses tryCatch inside to dispose such dangerous stuff.